# Adding user to phplist database

Tags: php, mysql, phplist

I'm trying to add a user to the phplist database. Adding the user is working, but they're not being added to the list.

```
     $uniqueId = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(0,1000).$email));
     $adduser = "INSERT INTO phplist_user_user (email, entered, confirmed, uniqid, htmlemail) VALUES ('".addslashes($email)."', 'now()', '1', '".addslashes($uniqueId)."', '1')";
     $save1 = mysql_query($adduser);
```

It works up to this point, but then the following code doesn't:

```
     $getid = "SELECT id FROM phplist_user_user WHERE uniqid='".addslashes($uniqueId)."'";
     $userId = mysql_query($getid);
     $addlist = "INSERT INTO phplist_listuser (userid,listid,entered) VALUES ('".addslashes($userId)."','2',now())";
     $save2 = mysql_query($addlist);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you mention which error it throws

Comment: Invalid query: Duplicate entry '0-2' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: You'll need to be sure that you use AUTO_INCREMENT on your primary keys, otherwise it will try to make them all 0, which it can't because primary keys have to be unique.

Comment: If listid is primary key in your phplist_listuser table ,then you should not require to add it from insert query as it will auto incremented and inserted automatically so remove field from this query which you mentioned as primary key here and make sure primary key is auto incremented in your table.

Comment: But the userid of phplist_listuser should be the UserId from phplist_user_user

Comment: @Trupti: listid is the ID of the list, you can say "static". e.g: i have three newsletter list: listid 1, listid 2 and listid 3

Comment: What is primary key in phplist_listuser table ? can you please provide structure ? only issue here is primary key unique rule is violating here.

Comment: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-26293147/listuser.png.html

Comment: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-26293154/user_user.png.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you didn't handle properly return of $getid query.

```
$getId = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM phplist_user_user WHERE uniqid='".addslashes($uniqueId)."'");
$fetchId = mysql_fetch_array($getId);
$userId = $fetchId['id'];
```

Now you can use $userId variable in $addlist

Answer (score 0):

No need to add user in phplist_tables , simply add in mysql -> create user phplistuser;

grant all permission to this user.

Please check phplist forums for further assistance.